# How to parse <rss> tag with XML::LibXML to find xmlns defintions

Tags: perl, rss

It seems that there is no consistent way that podcasts define their rss feeds.
Ran into one that is using different schema defs for the RSS.

What's the best way to scan for xmlnamespace in an RSS url, using XML::LibXML

E.g.

One feed might be

```
<rss 
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" 
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" 
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" version="2.0">
```

Another might be

```
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"version="2.0"
     xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

I want to include in my script an assessment of all the namespaces being used so that when parsing the rss, the appropriate field names can be tracked.

Not sure what that will look like yet, as I'm not sure this module has the capability to do the `<rss>` tag attribute atomization that I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what kind of output you're looking for, but [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML) is indeed able to list the namespaces:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'EOT');
<rss 
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" 
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" 
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" version="2.0">
</rss>
EOT
for my $ns ($dom->documentElement->getNamespaces) {
    print $ns->getLocalName(), " / ", $ns->getData(), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
content / http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/
wfw / http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/
dc / http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/
atom / http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
sy / http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/
slash / http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/
```

Comment: Thanks. That's perfect. I just needed a start. I was looking through the docs and was not seeing what I needed. Probably too stressed and kept overlooking the answer.

Comment: The XML::LibXML docs are quite extensive and dense (they're basically the entire XML spec) so I wouldn't fault anyone for overlooking something like this.

Comment: Interesting that you have to use `->documentElement`, because [XML::LibXML::Document](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod) is a [XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod), but its `getNamespaces` returns an empty list...

Comment: @StefanBecker Yes, in the [DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/), a "document" and "document element" are different things.

Answer (score 2):

I know that OP has already accepted an answer. But for completeness sake it should be mentioned that the recommended way to make searches on the DOM resilient is to use [XML::LibXML::XPathContext](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::XPathContext):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my @examples = (
    <<EOT
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <atom:test>One Ring to rule them all,</atom:test>
</rss>
EOT
    ,
    <<EOT
<rss xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <a:test>One Ring to find them,</a:test>
</rss>
EOT
    ,
    <<EOT
<rss xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <test>The end...</test>
</rss>
EOT
    ,
);

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

for my $example (@examples) {
    my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $example)
        or die "XML: $!\n";

    for my $node ($xpc->findnodes("//atom:test", $dom)) {
        printf("%-10s: %s\n", $node->nodeName, $node->textContent);
    }
}

exit 0;
```

i.e. you assign a local namespace prefix for those namespaces you are interested in.

Output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
atom:test : One Ring to rule them all,
a:test    : One Ring to find them,
test      : The end...
```

Comment: In fact after looking through your example. Resilient stands out as something important. And it is a big part of my approach to writing good code.

Comment: I could probably build a module to account for known namespace DTD's and follow your resilience pattern. I'll keep it in mind for a more robust version of what I'm doing.